# preventDefault not working with wheel event [SOLVED]

Tags: vue.js

EDIT: It worked by adding prevent modifier to the element in the template

I'm working on a slider that changes the slides on wheel event, I'm throttling the event to get it work just one time on each scroll, I have this piece of code

```
  <div
    ref="animated-figure"
    class="animated-figure-wrapper"
  >
     <h1 class="animated-figure__caption">YOU</h1>
  </div>

mounted() {
  this.$refs['animated-figure'].addEventListener('wheel', this.throttle(this.scrollDirection, 800));
},
methods: {
 throttle(func, interval) {
  let lastCall = 0;
  return function() {
    const now = Date.now();
    if (lastCall + interval < now) {
      lastCall = now;
      return func.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  };
 },
 scrollDirection(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  e.wheelDeltaY > 0
    ? console.log("DOWN")
    : console.log("UP")
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
 }
}
```

Prevent default here is not working as intended and it's continue scrolling, any ideas?

Comment: Can you share the template portion as well? Because I think there is a more elegant way of binding the event to your element, with .prevent modifier. [Vue Events](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) and [Vue Event Modifiers](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers)

Comment: @D.Schaller updated my question, when I tried this it didn't work

Comment: @D.Schaller I tried many times using .prevent in template but it didn't work, I tried it now it worked!! thank you